# How to show custom taxonomy child posts through shortcode in WordPress

Tags: plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, shortcode

My question: I have custom taxonomy in WP named Videos and childs of this taxonomy named music-videos and game-videos.

In my WP theme this is shortcode which shows ALL video posts from main taxonomy named VIDEOS:

```
    <?php
add_shortcode("video", "video_shortcode");
function video_shortcode($atts, $content) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        "items" => 3,
        "cat" => null,
        "id" => null,
        "nav" => false,
        "order" => "desc",
        "orderby" => "ID",
        "videos" => null
    ), $atts));
    $order       = strtoupper($order);
    $items_count = 0;
    $items_src   = null;
    if ($id == null) {
        $query = array(
            'post_type' => 'video',
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'order' => $order,
            'posts_per_page' => $items,
            'cat' => $cat
        );
        if (of_get_option('shortcat_video', '1') == '1') {
            $query = array(
                'posts_per_page' => $items,
                'orderby' => $orderby,
                'order' => $order,
                'post_type' => 'video',
                'tax_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'videos',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array(
                            $cat
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
        }
        if ($videos != null) {
            $query['tax_query'] = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'videos',
                    'field' => 'slug'
                )
            );
        }
        $wp_query_video = new WP_Query($query);
    }
    $items_src .= '    
   <div class="home-shr clearfix">
      <div class="vdshr-col">
         <div class="home-width">';
    while ($wp_query_video->have_posts()):
        $wp_query_video->the_post();
        global $post;
        $fix            = the_excerpt_max(0);
        $title          = get_the_title($fix);
        $video          = get_post_meta($post->ID, "video_link", true);
        $image_id       = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $venue          = get_post_meta($post->ID, "vd_venue", true);
        $data_video     = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'vd_date', true);
        $time           = strtotime($data_video);
        $pretty_date_yy = date('Y', $time);
        $pretty_date_M  = date('F', $time);
        $pretty_date_d  = date('d', $time);
        $cover          = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'video-shortcode');
        $cover_large    = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id, 'photo-large');
        $no_cover       = get_template_directory_uri();
        $items_src .= '
            <div class="vdshr-fix wz-last">
               <div class="vdshr-cover">
                  <div class="wz-wrap wz-hover">';
        if ($image_id) {
            $items_src .= '
                     <img src="' . $cover[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />';
        } else {
            $items_src .= '
                     <img src="' . $no_cover . '/images/no-cover/media-shr.png" alt="no image" />';
        }
        $items_src .= ' 
                     <div class="he-view">
                        <div class="bg a0" data-animate="fadeIn">
                           <a href="' . $video . '" class="vdshr-link a2" data-animate="zoomIn" data-rel="prettyPhoto"></a>
                           <a href="' . $cover_large[0] . '" class="vdshr-zoom a2" data-animate="zoomIn" data-rel="prettyPhoto-cover"></a>
                        </div>
                     </div>         
                  </div>
               </div><!-- end .vdshr-cover -->  
               <a href="' . $video . '" data-rel="prettyPhoto">
                  <div class="vdshr-info">  
                     <div class="vdshr-title">' . $title . '</div>';
        if ($data_video) {
            $items_src .= '
                     <div class="vdshr-des">' . $pretty_date_d . ' ' . $pretty_date_M . ' ' . $pretty_date_yy . '</div>';
        } else {
            $items_src .= '
                     <div class="vdshr-des">' . $venue . ' </div>';
        }
        $items_src .= '
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div><!-- end .vdshr-fix wz-last -->';
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();
    $items_src .= '    
         </div><!-- end .home-width -->
      </div><!-- end .vdshr-col -->
   </div><!-- end .home-shr clearfix -->';
    return $items_src;
}
?>
```

Question - how to show through shortcode only posts from child taxonomy: music-videos or only from games-videos?

Thank you for your time and patience, guys and gals

Comment: "child" taxonomy? Do you mean "get videos from a specific term in the taxonomy"?

Comment: Well you can put it in this way, if we look at videos as main category there are subcategories music-videos and game-videos. In my WP theme i have custom taxonomy videos and terms music-videos and game-videos

Answer (score 0):

That is a very messy shortcode but it looks like if you pass a term slug into the shortcode `cat` att this part...

```
if (of_get_option('shortcat_video', '1') == '1') {
    $query = array(
        'posts_per_page' => $items,
        'orderby' => $orderby,
        'order' => $order,
        'post_type' => 'video',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'videos',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array(
                    $cat
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
```

... would display those videos, except that the `of_get_option` conditional may be preventing that block from running. I don't know what that is or how it gets set. And since I don't know what that conditional is for I can't say what the result would be if you remove it. That `tax_query` component is what you need though.

If passing that slug doesn't work you probably need to create your own shortcode, which you could do by copying that one and altering the top part. Let me know if you need to do that and need help.

Comment: Thank you, i will do as you advice and post feedback than. Thank you very much